# Preferable mixed mode (SMPS + Linear) PSU topology

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, passive-networks, linear-regulator

I'm designing power supply for my hybrid headphone amplifier. It will be powered from external SMPS of unknown quality. Amp's power supply contains linear part (linear regulator + rail splitter) and 70V charge pump for tubes (post-regulation is omitted on diagrams).

Which topology would provide better isolation of linear part from switched?

[image: PSU topologies]

I have almost complete design using topology A, but now I'm in doubt if I should reroute it to topology B.

Comment: If I understood correctly the internal SMPS is connected in parallel with the linear PSU after the LC filterin option A? How do you prevent your SMPS from injecting noise into the input of your linear PSU? In this case B looks better

Comment: I agree. So I have changed topology and also have added separated switched mode ground.